# How to DI register FirebaseApp in .Net Core?

Tags: c#, .net-core, firebase-cloud-messaging

How should I register FirebaseApp instance in Net core?
As a singleton like

```
   //startup.cs
   services.AddSingleton<FirebaseApp>(sp =>
   {
       FirebaseApp.Create(new AppOptions
       {
           Credential = GoogleCredential.FromJson(settings)
       });
   });
```

Or as scoped similarly

```
   //startup.cs
   services.AddScoped<FirebaseApp>(sp =>
   {
       FirebaseApp.Create(new AppOptions
       {
           Credential = GoogleCredential.FromJson(settings)
       });
   });
```

Or some third option?

Comment: Looks like it support reconnects etc. so singletone is ok.

Comment: https://github.com/firebase/firebase-admin-dotnet/issues/50

Comment: An instance of FirebaseApp returned by FirebaseApp.Create() as a Singleton, you can refer to [example](http://handsonjones.com/2020/02/securing-a-website-using-firebase-angular-8-and-asp-net-core-3-1/).

Answer (score 1):

So right after the builder in .net 6 I just instantiate it using the following:

```cs
var builder = WebApplication.CreateBuilder(args);
// after the builder so that I can get the configurations for google credentials
// check if the instance is already loaded, if not build it up
if(FirebaseApp.DefaultInstance == null)
{
    FirebaseApp.Create(new AppOptions()
    {
        Credential = GoogleCredential.FromJson(AuthConfig.GetGoogleCredentialObject(builder.Configuration).ToString())
    });
}
```

Then, you don't need to inject it into the constructor of your classes.

You just call up the instance and load up the other firebase modules like so:

```cs
...
// this is a singleton and the props are static so available anytime
var customToken = FirebaseApp.DefaultInstance;

// use the instance from the singleton
await FirebaseAuth.GetAuth(customToken).SetCustomUserClaimsAsync(uid, additionalClaims);
....
```